# Array is not printing right values

Tags: c, arrays, max, coordinates, distance

My program is supposed to read 20 points from a .txt file and calculate two points that are at max and min distances from each other. I have done research and debugged the program multiple times but somehow the debugger is skipping the highlighted points altogether.

The program seems to work but it is not printing the correct values. My `x1` and `y1` coordinate are not coming out right. Let's say it should print

```
x1 = pointsarray[coord_1_min][0];
y1 = pointsarray[coord_1_min][1];
x2 = pointsarray[coord_2_min][0];            
y2 = pointsarray[coord_2_min][1];
```

but it is instead printing:

```
x1 = pointsarray[coord_1_min][0];
y1 = pointsarray[coord_1_min][1];
x2 = pointsarray[coord_1_min][1];            
y2 = pointsarray[coord_1_min+1][0];
```

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

int    MenuPrint();
double Distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2);
double LineLength( double pointsarray[][2], int number_of_points, int largest_or_smallest_line, double point1[][2], double point2[][2]);

int main()
{
    double pointsarray[20][2];
    double point1[1][2], point2[1][2];
    double vertex1[1][2], vertex2[1][2], vertex3[1][2];
    double x1,x2,y1,y2,x3,y3;

    int choice = 0;

    int number_of_points = 20;
    {
        double x[20], y[20];

        FILE *point;
        point = fopen("Asn06.txt", "r");

        for(int i = 0; i < number_of_points; i++)
        {
            fscanf_s( point , "%lf,%lf" , &x[i] , &y[i] );
        }

        for (int i=0 ; i < 20; i++)
        {
            pointsarray[i][0] = x[i];
            pointsarray[i][1] = y[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i=0 ; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%lf, %lf\n", pointsarray[i][0],pointsarray[i][1] );
    }

    choice = MenuPrint();

    while (choice == 1 || choice == 2)
    {
        int largest_or_smallest_line = choice;

        LineLength (pointsarray, number_of_points, largest_or_smallest_line, point1, point2);
        x1 = point1[0][0];
        y1 = point1[0][1];
        x2 = point2[0][0];
        y2 = point2[0][1];

        printf("Points are %5.2f, %5.2f and %5.2f, %5.2f\n",x1,y1,x2,y2);
        choice = MenuPrint();
    }

    while (choice == 3 || choice == 4)
    {
        int largest_or_smallest_area = choice;

        AreaDifferenciator (pointsarray, number_of_points, largest_or_smallest_area, vertex1, vertex2, vertex3 );
        x1 = vertex1[0][0];
        x2 = vertex2[0][0];
        x3 = vertex3[0][0];
        y1=  vertex1[0][1];
        y2 = vertex2[0][1];
        y3 = vertex3[0][1];

        printf("Points are %5.2f, %5.2f, %5.2f, %5.2f and %5.2f,%5.2f\n",x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3);
        choice = MenuPrint();
    }

    return 0;
}

int MenuPrint()
{
    int choice;

    printf("\nPlease choice a option:\n1> points closest together\n2> points further apart\n3>triangle with the smallest area\n4>triangle with the largest area\n5>exit\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &choice);
    return choice;
}

double Distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    double distance;

    distance = sqrt(pow((x1-x2),2)+pow((y1-y2),2));
    return distance;
}

double LineLength (double pointsarray[][1], int number_of_points, int largest_or_smallest_line, double point1[][2], double point2[][2])
{
    if (largest_or_smallest_line = 1)
    {
        double x1, y1, x2, y2;
        double dist, dist_Min;

        int i, j;
        int coord_1_min = 0;
        int coord_2_min = 1;

        x1 = pointsarray[coord_1_min][0];
        y1 = pointsarray[coord_1_min][1];
        x2 = pointsarray[coord_2_min][0];
        y2 = pointsarray[coord_2_min][1];

        dist_Min = Distance( x1, y1, x2, y2);

        for (i = 0; i < 19; i++)
        {
            for (j = i + 1; j < 20; j++)
            {
                x1 = pointsarray[i][0];
                y1 = pointsarray[i][1];
                x2 = pointsarray[j][0];
                y2 = pointsarray[j][1];

                dist = Distance( x1, y1, x2, y2);

                if (dist < dist_Min)
                {
                    coord_1_min = i;
                    coord_2_min = j;
                    dist_Min = dist;
                }
            }
        }

        pointsarray[coord_1_min][0] = x1;
        pointsarray[coord_1_min][1] = y1;
        pointsarray[coord_2_min][0] = x2;
        pointsarray[coord_2_min][1] = y2;

        point1[0][0] = x1;
        point1[0][1] = y1;
        point2[0][0] = x2;
        point2[0][1] = y2;
    }
    else if (largest_or_smallest_line = 2)
    {
        double x1, y1, x2, y2;
        double dist, dist_max;
        int i,j;
        int coord_1_max = 0;
        int coord_2_max = 1;

        x1 = pointsarray[coord_1_max][0];
        y1 = pointsarray[coord_1_max][1];
        x2 = pointsarray[coord_2_max][0];
        y2 = pointsarray[coord_2_max][1];

        dist_max = Distance( x1, y1, x2, y2);

        for (i = 0; i < 19; i++)
        {
            for (j = i + 1; j < 20; j++)
            {
                x1 = pointsarray[i][0];
                y1 = pointsarray[i][1];
                x2 = pointsarray[j][0];
                y2 = pointsarray[j][1];

                dist = Distance( x1, y1, x2, y2);

                if (dist > dist_max)
                {
                    coord_1_max = i;
                    coord_2_max = j;
                    dist_max = dist;
                }
            }
        }

        pointsarray[coord_1_max][0] = x1;
        pointsarray[coord_1_max][1] = y1;
        pointsarray[coord_2_max][0] = x2;
        pointsarray[coord_2_max][1] = y2;

        point1[0][0] = x1;
        point1[0][1] = y1;
        point2[0][0] = x2;
        point2[0][1] = y2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give sample input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: The `if` and `else if` in the `LineLength` function are using `=` when they should be using `==`.